RandomInteger function to create a list of 10 elements with either Red or Yellow color element
While following the docs on RandomInteger, it seems mostly covering operations on integers.
But RandomInteger should be applied on other data types such as color as well.

Could anyone please suggest me how to create a list of 10 elements that will have a block of red or yellow as each element chosen randomly making use of RandomInteger function.

That's why Part is mentioned in the question. Think carefully about how to combine RandomInteger and Part. Notice Part can be used in various ways.

Not that it uses Part but a variation could be: RandomChoice[{Red, Yellow, Green}, 100]

Using Part:
Part[{Red, Yellow, Green}, RandomInteger[{1, 3}, 100]]

As already observed there are many ways to achieve, e.g. RandomChoice:
RandomChoice[{Red, Yellow, Green}, 100]



Join[Part[RandomChoice[{Red, Yellow, Green}, 100], All], RandomInteger[{1, 3}, 0]]



Yes I know that the above is a superfluous use of RandomInteger and Part.

data=RandomInteger[{1,3},100]


data/.{1->Red,2->Yellow,3->Green}



The question requires one to use Part

Opps, OK, how about
data=RandomInteger[{1,3},100]
Which[ Part[data, #] == 1, Red,
   Part[data, #] == 2, Yellow,
   Part[data, #] == 3, Green 
   ]& /@Range[100]



The question requires one to use Part :)
